# Lista de opções da pergunta quebrando linha

Tags: bug, status-intencional

Acredito que essa quebra de linha seja um *bug*:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Talvez seja para evitar exatamente isso: [Assinatura da pergunta a passar para a coluna direita do site](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1056/3117)

Comment: E provavelmente uma duplicata disso: [Formatação das opções da pergunta está quebrada](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/566/3117)

Comment: @Math Parece uma discussão antiga então